# unable to display the data in the datatable

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm trying to display the data after doing a post request. Im able to console the data in the datatable but it doesnt get displayed in the datatable.

I called the datatable function after storing the data in an array. But **it gives me an error**. It shows `aDataSort is undefined`.

I call the datatable function on `ngOnInit()` so that error doesn't get displayed.

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
        class="row-border hover">
</table>




ngOnInit() {

  this.dataTable()
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
// this.dtTrigger.next();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
// Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
 this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
}

rerender(): void {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
  // Destroy the table first
  dtInstance.destroy();
  // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
  this.dtTrigger.next();
  });
 }

 dataTable() {
 console.log(this.scannedData);
 let self = this;
 this.dtOptions = {
  data: this.scannedData,

  columnDefs: [
    {
      'targets': 0,
      render: function () {
        let checkbox = `
           <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">`;
        return checkbox;
      }
    }
  ],
  columns: [

    {
      title:"Select"
    },

    {
      title: "Name",
      data: "data.name"
    },
    {
      title: "Email",
      data: "data.email"
    },
    {
      title: "Phone",
      data: "data.phone"
    },
    {
      title: "Experience",
      data: "data.experience"
    },
    {
      title: "Score",
      data: "data.score"
    }
  ],
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    const self = this;
    $("td", row).unbind("change");
    $("td", row).bind("change", () => {
      self.onSelect(data);
    });

    $("td .checkbox", row).unbind("change");
    $("td .checkbox", row).bind("change", event => {
      this.toggle(data);
    });

    return row
  }
 }
}

scanJob() {
 let scanner = new FormData;
 scanner.set('id', this.jobProfileId);
 this.scanner.scanJob(scanner).subscribe(res => {
  this.scannedData = JSON.parse(res);
  this.dataTable();
  console.log(this.scannedData);
},
  error => {
    console.log("error");

  }
 )
}
```

I want to see the data in the datatble

Comment: Could you share your HTML code?

Comment: Edited the code. The thing is when i call the datatable function on Init it gives the table headers but not the data. It shows no data available. But I want the datatable to get the data after the scan method only. If i call the datatable method in the scan method only it shows an error stating aDataSort is undefined.